# Help my polkadot-local test chain stops producing blocks

Tags: polkadot-local

[image]

```
2022-05-21 09:25:54  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xc5a1eca5753c3513550364b882d0be1ab4955dd883d0ab65b25ad1dc5268f9f5
2022-05-21 09:25:54 [#690]   Failed to finalize election round. reason ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")
2022-05-21 09:25:54 [#690]   Entering emergency mode: ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")
2022-05-21 09:25:54 [690]  election provider failed due to ElectionError::Fallback("NoFallback.")
2022-05-21 09:25:54  Prepared block for proposing at 690 (1 ms) [hash: 0xd827bb2b3ede09499adc80542aa2a0bf2bec2a08c5bfa62d85d607aa7ab71b82; parent_hash: 0xc5a1…f9f5; extrinsics (2): [0x7480…f745, 0x27ed…60f3]]
2022-05-21 09:25:54  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 690. Hash now 0x8554362fbdf7bdefa131a554a5e54f280c8156b056797f41586e77806151e9ff, previously 0xd827bb2b3ede09499adc80542aa2a0bf2bec2a08c5bfa62d85d607aa7ab71b82.
2022-05-21 09:25:54 Error with block built on 0xc5a1eca5753c3513550364b882d0be1ab4955dd883d0ab65b25ad1dc5268f9f5: Import failed: Unexpected epoch change
```

Running with fast-runtime polkadot 0.9.22-dfd09150a03:

polkadot 
--base-path /tmp/alice 
--chain polkadot-local 
--alice 
--validator 
--wasm-execution Compiled 
--prometheus-external 
--out-peers=10 
--rpc-external 
--rpc-cors=all 
--rpc-methods=unsafe 
--unsafe-rpc-external 
--unsafe-ws-external 
--name "Alice"

On multiple occasions (after wiping data) my local chain stops producing blocks sometimes after a few hours otherwise within an era or two.

Comment: How many nodes does your network have?

Comment: 2 validator slots, 3 nodes set to validate, 4 nodes in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about MacOS is it's very efficient, It is not obvious that it sleeps! however this is something it does seamlessly and to which will have negative effects on anything time bound such as blockchains.

I suspect that as the process is suspended at Time X it wakes in Time Z and has warped through time, thus causing an unexpected epoch in BABE.
I also suspect this can impact GRANDPA in a similar way both these consensus components can be halted due to unexpected time warps.

Moral of the story turn off power saving features or run caffeinate or some other tool to keep your development workspace alive.